# Java split() with regex

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have been trying to split up a String, which contain a number of words separated by a random amount of spaces

```
String numbers = " 3534   65 884    76 45   34";

String[] listOfnumbers = numbers.split("\\s+");
```

but I keep getting an empty string saved in the first position of the array.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I imagine your String `record` has a leading space if you are getting such an output, but you haven't posted the input or output to your expression.

Comment: Shouldn't that be disregarded as the regex I use ignores all spaces?

Comment: put input and output example so we can understand more

Comment: No, it does not ignore spaces, it splits at any occurrence of multiple spaces. So if there is a leading space(s), there is a null string before those spaces.

Comment: From [the docs for `Sting.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-): "When there is a positive-width match [to the delimiter pattern] at the beginning of this string then an empty leading substring is included at the beginning of the resulting array."

Comment: @YCF_L I updated the code and included an input example

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ah thanks, I should have looked at the documentation before asking

Comment: @k238 one or more spaces is the delimiter. So if you string is `String s = " a b c"` then `s.split("\\s+")` would produce `["", "a", "b", "c"]`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I see, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to trim the string first?

```
record.trim().split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 2):

this should do the trick:

```
String[] recordData = record.trim().split("\\s+");
```